# Getting div data which has empty spaces in its class field

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

I have a page that I need to parse which is :

```
<div class="shadowBox someOtherBox">
    .
    .
    .
</div>

.
.
.
<div class="shadowBox other">
    <h2>OTHERS</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/link/to/something/1" target="_self">TITLE #1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/link/to/something/2" target="_self">TITLE #2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/link/to/something/3" target="_self">TITLE #3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to get each link inside `<div class="shadowBox other">` and its TITLE. I tried to do this in many different ways, but at the end I couldn't managed to do it. Here is the code for one of my tries;

```
function parse(crn)
    {
        request("LINK_OF_PAGE", function(error, response, html)
        {
            if(!error)
            {
                var $ = cheerio.load(html);
                var title, news_url, url_hash;
                var json = { title : "", news_url : ""};

                var links = [];

                var data = $('div').filter('.shadowBox').last();

                //var data = $('.shadowBox.other').children('ul').children('li').children('a');
                console.log(data);

                news_url = data.prev().text();
                url_hash = md5(news_url);
            }
        });
    }
```

Why my logic doesn't work? How would I achieve what I want?

Comment: Your title of the question and description does not match. Will you please update with actual problem statement.

Comment: `var $ = cheerio.load(html);` - This line screws it up.

Comment: Would you suggest a title for me? I couldn't come up with sensible one.

Comment: @OğuzhanDurgun If you want to collect the text of those anchors then you can use https://jsfiddle.net/kft8mjub/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to populate the links array with the href and text value of anchor elemnets then

```
var links = $('.shadowBox.other li a').map(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    return { title : $this.attr('href'), news_url : $this.text()}
}).get();
```